# edit LyX nomenclature command extensions

Tags: lyx, glossaries

I want to edit LyX's nomenclature command to use `makeglossaries` in stead of `makeindex`. This can be don the the settings menu under Output > LaTeX.

Here I can change

```
makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o
```

to

```
makeglossaries
```

however, I cannot specify that LyX uses the `[filename].glo` as an input instead of `[filename].nlo`, and that is uses `[filename.gls]` as in output in stead of `[filename].nls`.

Is there any way to change this manually?

EDIT: I found that the preferences file only says:

```
\nomencl_command "makeglossaries"
```

but the log output says:

```
makeglossaries "[filename].nlo" -o [filename].nls
```

So where is `\nomencl_command` defined further?